# Why is my new list outputting an empty one when I should be getting an answer

Tags: python, list, sentiment-analysis

I'm having problems with my code where I'm trying to add to a new list all words that match a given list (in order at the end to have a basic sentiment analysis code). I have tried passing it through Python Tutor but have had no success. In short, I'm expecting an output of the word **great** but instead get an **empty list**.

```py
def remove_punc_and_split (wordlist) : 
    punc = '.!?/:;,{}'  #the punctuation to be removed
    no_punc = "" 
    for char in wordlist :
        if char not in punc :
            no_punc = no_punc + char.lower()
    new_word_list = no_punc.split() #dividing the words into seperate strings in a list
    return new_word_list

def sentiment1 (wordlist1):
    positive_words = ["good","awesome","excellent","great"]
    wordlist1 = remove_punc_and_split (comment_1)
    pos_word_list = []                                                               
    for postive_words in wordlist1 :
        if wordlist1[0] == positive_words :
            pos_word_list.append(wordlist1)
            print(wordlist1)
    return pos_word_list
    
comment_1 = 'Good for the price, but poor Bluetooth connections.'
sentiment1(comment_1)
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: sorry, I did not understand how to put in my snippet of code, this has now been rectified

Comment: np, removed my downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be to use [`set.intersection`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection) method for this to find common values between `positive_words` and the input list. I also updated it to pass the lowercased sentence `wordlist1.lower()` to the remove punc function, because you want to do a case-insensitive match against `positive_words`; so first you will need to lowercase all characters in the sentence before you can check if there are any positive words.

```py
def sentiment1(wordlist1):
    positive_words = {"good", "awesome", "excellent", "great"}
    wordlist1 = remove_punc_and_split(wordlist1.lower())
    pos_word_list = list(positive_words.intersection(wordlist1))
    return pos_word_list
```